# what's the most used tag library in spring MVC projects

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags, taglib

I find JSP tag libraries (like struts tag library) easier to use compared to tag files or JSTL tags. But what's the most commonly used JSP tag library in Spring MVC projects?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the Spring's form tag library as it is integrated with Spring Web MVC, giving the tags access to object and data your controller deals with.

Comment: Ken, Struts tag library consists of four libraries Bean, HTML, Logic, and Nested. Are all these functionalities provided by Spring's form tag library?

Comment: Struts tag library is just a collection of  custom jsp tag .You can use JSP as a view in the spring mvc , so I suppose you can use struts tag library in Spring Web MVC

Comment: Yes. I use struts tag libraries in Spring Web MVC framework. I wanted to know if struts is the mostly used tag library or there's another. Thanks for your response.